# Why should session cookies have a short TTL?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

I am currently working on the development of a Central Authentication Service (CAS) with the aim of streamlining user management and authentication processes across all of my projects. The primary objective is to eliminate the need for separate user management systems and authentication protocols for each individual project.

The CAS operates on a cookie-based mechanism, where users, upon signing in, receive a domain-wide usable cookie. This cookie serves as a means of authorization for other services, allowing them to authenticate the user without the need for redundant login processes.

During my research, I came across various articles and forums emphasizing the importance of setting short Time-to-Live (TTL) values for session cookies to mitigate the risk of cookie hijacking attacks. However, my system takes a different approach by incrementing the TTL on the server side, rather than refreshing the cookie at regular intervals. I am currently grappling with understanding the practical utility of this method, as it seems that once an attacker obtains the original cookie, they could potentially perpetually acquire refreshed cookies from the server, making be unsure about the effectiveness of this approach in enhancing security.